# How to get list's itself while RowMapping with Maven in java

Tags: java, database, list, maven, rowmapper

I am getting an error because of the type required in emails. It requires List<java.lang.String> but I wanted to ask would `.emails((List<String>) resultSet.getObject("emails"));` work for that situation?

```
private final RowMapper<Company> sampleRowMapper = (resultSet, i) -> new Company()
          .name(resultSet.getString("name"))
          .country(resultSet.getString("country"))
          .phoneNumber(resultSet.getString("phoneNumber"))
          .emails(resultSet.getObject("emails"));
```

Also, the email part is like this.

```
public Company emails(List<String> e_mails) {
    this.e_mails = e_mails;
    return this;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with

```
.emails(Collections.singletonList("e_mails"));
```